# What exactly are the restrictions that CORS places when retrieving image URLs from another website?

Tags: javascript, html, cors

Suppose if my domain is A and I want to display an image from domain B I can do this successfully by placing the image URL from B in the src attribute of the img tag on my website and expect the picture to display. However when I try to display the image on a canvas and convert it to base64 using the toDataUrl function I am unable to do so due to CORS reasons.

My questions are - How come I get to display the image from domain B if it does allow cross origin resource sharing? Is it only a HTTP header setting on domain B that must be configured in order to allow my domain A to access the resource or is there a setting on domain A that needs to be activated as well?

Answer (score 2):

CORS doesn't place any restrictions. The Same Origin Policy places restrictions. CORS can remove some of them.

There is no restriction on **displaying** images.

`<img alt="" src="//cross-origin.example.com/foo.jpeg">` is absolutely fine (although the site could attempt to defeat that by testing the `referer` header with server side code).

By default, JavaScript is prevented from accessing the data inside the image (e.g. [placing the image on a `<canvas>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) and then generating a `data:` URL from it which the JavaScript could then pass on to the server).

CORS can lift *that* restriction with an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: ```+1``` just for that first paragraph. :-) But you might want to address the question about headers, etc.

Comment: So basically the server at domain B has to send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in its reply?

Comment: @IkimSS — Not for Site A to simply display the image, no. That's allowed automatically. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068  for an overview of how CORS works.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it only a HTTP header setting on domain B that must be configured in order to allow my domain A to access the resource...

Yes, to indicate to the browser that it's safe for the origin domain B gives permission to to use the image, for instance:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://domaina.example`

Depending on how the image is being retrieved, it may need further headers to allow credentials or headers, but that's the main one.

Domain A doesn't need anything special, just code using the image data.

Full details in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/).